# in bar-highcharts useing datepicker why showing previous data when no data on nextdate

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Highcharts.chart('day-container', {
 chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                            }, 
 xAxis: {
                                categories: ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19'],
                                labels: {
                                    rotation:-45
                                },
 series: [{     
                                name: 'Energy[kWh]',
                                data: ydata,


                            }] ,
                            lang: {
                                noData: "No Data"
                            }
```